# How to force table to maintain the margins

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I created a table using LaTeX, but as shown in the image, the table width spans to reach the page width as well. I want to maintain the margin in the page.

How can I do that?

**code**:

```
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l| }
 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Symbols Directory} \\
 \hline
 $A$ & is the state transition matrix in Kalman Filter and it is a square   
 matrix of nxn \\
 $\textbf{x}_\textbf{k}$ & is the state vector in Kalman Filter with nx1     
 dimension \\
  $B$ & is the control matrix  in Kalman Filter and it is of dimension mxn   
  \\
 $\textbf{u}$ & is the control vector  in Kalman Filter and it is of 
 dimension mx1 \\
 $w$ & process noise ”error source”  in Kalman Filter and it is of nx1   
 dimension \\
 $P_k$ & is the estimated covariance matrix  in Kalman Filter with nxn   
 dimension \\
  $Q$ & is the process noise covariance matrix  in Kalman Filter with nxn  
 dimension \\
 $R$ & is the measurement noise covariance matrix  in Kalman Filter with mxm 
 dimension \\
 $\hat{x}k$ & is the adjusted or the corrected state variables  in Kalman 
 Filter with nx1 dimension \\
 $K$ & is Kalman gain in Kalman Filter \\
 $\bigtriangleup{T}$ & The traveling time spans from the GPS signal emission  
 till the GPS reception\\
 $t_r$ & Time at which the GPS signal received\\
 $t_e$ & Time at which the GPS signal emitted\\

 \hline
 \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: You can have a look at [`tabularx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and/or [`tabulary`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) packages: they specified the total width of your table.

Comment: you have specified `l` columns which specifies left aligned and no line breaking use `p{5cm}` to line break to 5cm, or the packages ebo mentioned

Comment: @DavidCarlisle would u please tell me how to solve it

Comment: why have you tagged this with every tag except tables?

Comment: add `\usepackage{tabularx}` then change `|l|l|` to `|l|X|`

Comment: As David Carlisle points out, use `\usepackage{tabularx}`, change `\begin{tabular}{ |l|l| }` to `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |l|X| }`, and `\end{tabular}` to `\end{tabularx}`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way, with `tabularx`. This is a case where vertical rules are preferred, in my opinion. I changed the alignment of the first column to `r`, and used the `showframe` option of `geometry` to check it each row fits within the margins:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, x11names]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, tabularx}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{r!{\enspace\color{Grey0!70!RoyalBlue1!50!}\vrule width1.2pt\enspace}X }

\multicolumn{2}{c}{\itshape Symbols Directory} \\[1.5ex]
$A$ & is the state transition matrix in Kalman Filter and it is a square
matrix of $ n × n $ \\
$\mathbf{x_k}$ & is the state vector in Kalman Filter with $ n × 1 $ dimension \\
$B$ & is the control matrix in Kalman Filter and it is of dimension $m × n $ \\
$\textbf{u}$ & is the control vector in Kalman Filter and it is of
dimension $ m × 1 $ \\
$w$ & process noise ”error source” in Kalman Filter and it is of $ n × 1 $
dimension \\
$P_k$ & is the estimated covariance matrix in Kalman Filter with $ n × n $ dimension \\
$Q$ & is the process noise covariance matrix in Kalman Filter with $ n × n $ dimension \\
$R$ & is the measurement noise covariance matrix in Kalman Filter with $ m × m $ dimension \\
$\hat{x}k$ & is the adjusted or the corrected state variables in Kalman
Filter with $ n × 1 $ dimension \\
$K$ & is Kalman gain in Kalman Filter \\
$\bigtriangleup{T}$ & The traveling time spans from the GPS signal emission
till the GPS reception\\
$t_r$ & Time at which the GPS signal received\\
$t_e$ & Time at which the GPS signal emitted
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change the line into `\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} |l|p{11cm}|}` and compile. The width of second column can be increased or decreased depending upon the right margin you require.